# Connecting to SQL Server on EC2 | Elastic IP vs Elastic IP Public DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, sql-server, amazon-ec2, ip

Based on this excellent [article](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal) by [@esh](http://twitter.com/esh) on using external Elastic IP DNS names internally within EC2, I am in the process of changing my connection strings for my web server to connect to a DB server (MSSQL instance) via the elastic IP DNS name rather than the elastic IP address itself.

The issue I have found is that I can connect to the SQL instance using the elastic IP address fine, but when I connect using the elastic IP DNS name I get the following connection error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I understand this resolves to the internal IP address but is there any implication with security groups, the firewall or SQL configuration that would cause this error?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Knowing the specific version can help me fine-tune the help I provide.

Comment: Hi John - it's SQL Server 2008 Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and give these instructions a try. If they work for you, awesome. If not, we'll continue to dig.

"GO START -> ALL PROGRAMS -> SQL SERVER 2008/2005/2008 R2
->CONFIGURATION TOOLS->
->SELECT SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER

->SELECT SQL SERVER NETWORK CONFIGURATION

->SELECT PROTOCOLS FOR MSSQLSERVER(YOUR INSTANCE NAME)

->IN RIGHT TASK PANEL
->MAKE SURE MENTION BELOW:

DISABLE SHARED MEMORY AND VIA
ENABLE NAMED PIPE AND TCP/IP

—-MAKE SAME CHANGES IN

->SQL NATIVE CLIENT 10.0(SERVER VERSION) CONFIGURATION – CLIENT PROTOCOLS

RESTART SQL SERVER(MSSQLSERVER [YOUR INSTANCE NAME]) SERVICE"

Give it a try, let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: It's odd, I've fired up the instances in question this morning to make your suggested changes and the DNS names now resolve and I can connect to the DB. I wonder if stopping the instances and effectively disassociating and associating the Elastic IPS to the instance reset something? 

Regardless, thanks for your suggestion - I'll bear them in mind should I get any similar issues.